# Laravel - use years as pagination numbers

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-5.1

I am on Laravel 5.1.45 (LTS). One club has many events.

I want to display a page which lists all the events for the current year (the default page). At the bottom at the page I want the links for the previous and for the next years (one link per page and one page per year).

This is my PublicController:

```
public function index()
{
    $events = Event::with('Club')
        ->orderBy('date', 'desc')
        ->get()
        ->groupBy(function($date) {
            return Carbon::parse($date->date)->format('Y');
        });

    $currentPage = Paginator::resolveCurrentPage() - 1;
    $perPage = 1;
    $currentPageSearchResults = $events->slice($currentPage * $perPage, $perPage)->all();
    $paginator = new LengthAwarePaginator($currentPageSearchResults, count($events), $perPage);

    return view('events.index', ['events' => $paginator]);
}
```

And this is my view:

```
@foreach ($events as $year)
    @foreach ($year as $object)
            {{ $object->date }}
            {{ ... }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach

{!! $events->setPath('/events/events')->appends(Request::except('page'))->render() !!}
```

This is working; I get all the events for the year in one page and one page for each year.

However, the links at the bottom of the page are, of course, in the form of, for example, '?page=2' for the 2016 events.

What I would like to have is a link in the form of '?page=YEAR'. And, if there are already events listed for the next year, to land on the page with the events for the current year if no parameter has been added to the URL.

Is that even possible?

Comment: Why `?page=YEAR` and not actually `?year=YEAR` ?

Comment: Sure, I can rename 'page' to 'year' if I want to. The question is about how to replace the default pagination numbers with the years.

Comment: You don't. Page is page and year or other filter is something different. What will you do, if you have too much data for one year? Like 2015 has 50000 entries? How will you paginate that if 2015 is already page? You filter by year, and then paginate those results.

Comment: The only purpose of you using the built in paginator here is for generating the pagination links and to fetch the page number. Both of which can be easily done with little effort. You're even fetching all the results from the db and then slicing them based on your condition. You're idea of pagination is totally wrong. Just stop using the built in paginator and write a custom one to handle this. You can even publish and customize laravel paginator view to help make things even easier.

Comment: Yes @DainisAbols I misunderstood your comment. There won't be 50000 entries but using a filter by year makes more sense. Thank you.